# Add '#' in XML file using Batch script

Tags: windows, batch, script, cmd.exe, text-editing

I am very new to batch scripting. 
Could you please let me know how I can add "#" in an XML file
– second line first letter – and save it in Windows.

[image: Screenshot]

As per the above screenshot, I need to add one more "#" in the second line
using Windows CMD.

Comment: What language is the script to be written in (Windows Cmd, PowerShell, Linux bash, etc)? Where is the '#' supposed to be added exactly?

Comment: @grawity batch script hints to Windows CMD. But other than that, this quesiton is lacking lots of info indeed.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

To take a file `config.xml`
add a `#` to the beginning of the second line,
and save the result as `config2.xml`,
create and run the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set line=1
(
    for /f "delims=" %%A in (config.xml) do (
        if !line!==2 (
            echo #%%A
        ) else (
            echo %%A
        )
        set /a line=line+1
    )
) > config2.xml
```

- `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is necessary to use variables
  in compound commands like loops.
- `set line=1` creates a variable called “`line`” that counts the lines.
- `for /f "delims=" %%A in (config.xml) do` reads `config.xml`
  one line at a time and assigns its contents to the variable `%%A`.
- `"delims="` says that there are no word delimiters. 
  Normally `for /f` breaks lines apart into words. 
  This option says that each entire line should be treated as a single “word”.
- The next five lines of code
  write out the line from the file (in `%%A`) as is,
  unless this is the second line of the file,
  in which case we write a `#` followed by the original line from the file.
- `set /a line=line+1` adds one to the line counter.

If you want the results in the original file, add

```
move /y config2.xml config.xml
```

at the end of batch file
(or do it yourself, manually, after you have verified
that `config2.xml` contains what you want).

Answer (score 1):

You have provided little information so I'm going to make assumptions here.

I assume you just want to place a # at the very end of a file.

In a .bat or .cmd file, you can accomplish by adding the following line to your code:

```
echo # >> filename.xml
```

Comment: I voted to reopen the question because the question was edited by the author so it's clear enough although its quality otherwise is unchanged.

Comment: @karel I agree. This is not doable in CMD though, but I voted to reopen this nontheless.

Comment: If you provide PowerShell command(s) I will try it on my computer.

Comment: @karel its really not that easy. Powershell is an advanced scripting language. Unless you already are very familiar with programming languages and syntax, this is not gonna work. But google will help you very easily to get started. SuperUser just is not the place unless you have a script and some knowledge to begin with.